# Disable HTTP/2 in IE11

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer-11, http2

I have a particularly knarly IE11 bug that *appears* to be caused by HTTP/2.  At present the only evidence I have is that if Fiddler is intercepting (therefore forcing HTTP/1.1) the bug goes away.

In order to isolate it I really need to turn off HTTP/2 in IE11.

I've disabled HTTP/2 in *Internet Options* and rebooted the computer but IE11 stubbornly carries on using HTTP/2.

[image: Internet Options]

Does anyone who what this setting actually does?
Does anyone know how to disable HTTP/2 in IE11?

Comment: You could try to clear cache in IE and test again. You could also try to edit the [group policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/new-group-policy-settings-for-ie11) and [regedit](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/4032720/how-to-deploy-custom-cipher-suite-ordering-in-windows-server-2016) to disable http/2 in IE. But in my test, it's more like a bug in IE that almost all the https use the http/2 protocol even after change so you could try to use http.

Comment: @YuZhou Haven't looked at the registry yet, done the other things though.  On the one hand I'm glad it's not just me, but on the other I was hoping it was something I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

It’s a design change of Wininet component which enabled HTTP2 by default for AppContainer and LowIL processes. As we know , most of IE content process (internet and restricted zone) run as Low integrity level.

So we have two workaround:
1.  Disable LCIE;
2.  Add the specified URL to trust site zone or intranet zone.